# cannot convert from 'cv::Mat' to 'void *'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

It seemed that I am the only one who got this problem with Opencv 2.4.3.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html
The following codes are published on that official website:

```
Size patternsize(8,6); //interior number of corners
Mat gray = ....; //source image
vector<Point2f> corners; //this will be filled by the detected corners

//CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK saves a lot of time on images
//that do not contain any chessboard corners
bool patternfound = findChessboardCorners(gray, patternsize, corners,
        CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
        + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);

if(patternfound)
  cornerSubPix(gray, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1),
    TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));

drawChessboardCorners(img, patternsize, Mat(corners), patternfound);
```

`gray` is `Mat`, and it is directly used as `void*`

But on my visual studio 2010, it kept saying Error

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'cvFindChessboardCorners' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cv::Mat' to 'const void *'    22
```

And, I have tried the following, but still the same error.

```
static_cast<void*>(gray)
Error   1   error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'cv::Mat' to 'void *'  21


(void*)gray
Error   1   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'cv::Mat' to 'void *'    21
```

I m using OpenCV 2.4.3. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code in the OpenCV documentation uses the C++ interface (`findChessboardCorners`). You're calling the C interface (`cvFindChessboardCorners`). If it's possible for you to use the C++ interface, I'd highly recommend it. I think you should be able to use the C++ interface, because if your code were compiling as C, I don't think it would complain about a cast to a void pointer (although maybe I'm mistaken there!).

Note: Depending upon namespaces, you may have to call the function like this:

`cv::findChessboardCorners`

You should be able to directly pass your `gray` object without any casting.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But why the C function does not accept any cast?

Comment: It may have compiled using using reinterpret_cast<void*>(gray). But the trouble is that even still, that's not the behaviour you want. The C interface is *not* meant to work with objects generated by OpenCV's C++ interface. `cv::Mat` is the C++ way of dealing with images -- it's part of the C++ interface. The C way of dealing with images was the `IplImage*` type. That would have casted directly to `void*` with no explicit cast required, but then you'd be using OpenCV's C interface. Stick with C++!

Comment: Thanks, I think I should look up more about casting. If I have got 15 reputation, I would thumb up. :)